# Unable to read data from Bluetooth Health Device for Android 6

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on android application to connect to Bluetooth Health Devices - Pulse oximeter,

i tried the following code:

```html
BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
// UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

 InputStream is = null;
 OutputStream os = null;
 mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            is = mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            
byte[] status = new byte[1];
            // read first byte
is.read(status);
            Log.d("status",String.valueOf(status));
```

I application seem to get stuck while reading from inputstream.

Similar question has been asked before. But no answers recieved.

Please help if any body found solution to this issue

Comment: is it a BLE device?  plz post u r complete code to see the issue.

Comment: No it is classic bluetooth device